# Pronunciation of "au revoir" by regional accent?

Tags: prononciation, régionalismes, accents-régionaux

Could someone please give examples of the differences in the pronunciation of "Au revoir" by regional accent (Belgium, etc)?

Comment: I don't see any, excepted the quite wide variations in the pronunciation of `r` and elisions made in more relaxed level of language (which isn't a regional variation).

Comment: Belgium: The _au_ is usually prononced short like in the word _mot_ instead of like in _haut_. (I'm quite flabbergasted that the IPA codes for both is `[o]`, by the way.)

Comment: @Joubarc, for once we differ. I pronounce _au revoir_ with [o], not with [ɔ].

Comment: To be clear, I think the `[o]` pronunciation is incorrect, but that's the way we say it most of the time anyway.

Comment: @Joubarc: This is no worse than the fact that the French and American "L" are given the same letter in IPA, despite being radically different sounds...

Comment: *au* is sometimes pronounced `[ɑ̃]` near Orléans.

Comment: Lots of comments- no votes, no answers.  What's the deal?

Comment: No votes : imho the comments should be included in the question, as is it is not detailed enough. No answer : well, nobody has one, give us some time :)

Comment: Probably because the question cannot be answered in full by just one person.

Comment: @Joubarc: funny, I pronounce *mot* and *haut* similarly, and can't think of any one doing the distinction…

Comment: I dunno why but I always pronounced *au* like *en* (for au revoir). I live in IDF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Official pronunciation: `[o ʁə.vwaʁ]` — see [le wiktionnaire](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/au_revoir)
- Global: the *e* in *revoir* is often omitted as in *au r'voir*, so *revoir* is closer to `[rvwar]`
- Belgium: a lot of people shorten the *au* and thus pronounce `[ɔ]` instead of `[o]`
- Orléans: *au* is sometimes pronounced `[ɑ̃]`

Comment: I can't see the Orléans phonetic markings.

Comment: The prononciation mentionned for Orléans is one we hear often in Lorraine (with a leading [ɑ̃] sound). The omission of the [ə] is standard also, for a final result of [ɑ̃rvwar].

Answer (score 3):

I'm from the south of the Poitou-Charentes (precisely often in Cognac, Saintes and La Rochelle) and as Joubarc mentions, it is also common there to hear either `[ɔʁvwaʁ]` or `[ɑ̃ʁvwaʁ]` (what I personally say).